# What does "lead those states to meet the demands of the leader making threats" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audience_cost#cite_note-7), I saw the explanation for "audience cost"

> The term was popularized in a 1994 academic article by James Fearon
> where he argued that democracies carry greater audience costs than
> authoritarian states, which makes them better at signaling their
> intentions in interstate disputes. It is one of the mechanisms for
> [democratic peace theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_peace_theory#:%7E:text=The%20democratic%20peace%20theory%20posits,motivating%20peace%20between%20democratic%20states.)
>
> In international relations theory, an audience cost is the electoral
> penalty a leader incurs from his or her constituency if they escalate
> a foreign policy crisis and are then seen as backing down. It is one
> of the mechanisms for democratic peace theory. It is associated with
> rational choice scholarship in international relations.
>
> The implication of audience costs is that threats issued by leaders
> (who incur audience costs) against other states are more likely to be
> seen as credible and thus lead those states to meet the demands of the
> leader making threats.

And what does "**lead those states to meet the demands of the leader making threats**" mean in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To lead"  means "to cause", so because the threats are credible, they cause [the countries that receive the threats] [to do something]

"Credible threats" are ones that the person will believe will be carried out.

The thing that is caused is "to meet the demands of the person making the threat".  "Meet" means "comply with"

> You must stop refining uranium [demand] or we will bomb your industries and airbases [threat].

This could cause the country to stop refining uranium.  That would "meet the demand".

The general idea is that threats made by democratic leaders are more believable (=credible) than threats made by dictators.

If a democratic leader threatens war, then backs down, they look bad to their own people.  If a dictator threatens war then backs down it doesn't matter to them (they rule by power and fear, not mass support).

So a dictator might make lots of fake threats, but if a democratic leader makes a threat it must be real. Democratic leaders make fewer threats, but are more likely to carry out the threat if they don't get what they want.

Comment: a very clear explanation, thanks @James K

Comment: even it seems that I catch your idea, I want to ask about what does this sentence "they look bad to their own people" mean then ?

Comment: And "the threats are credible", so "credible" here means "good reputation" to the supporters of these leaders ?

Comment: Credible means "believable" A credible threat is one that that you think will be carried out.

Comment: Can I ask about your political background.  Are you living in a democratic country?  Do you live in a country where the leader cares about what the people's opinion is.  In democratic countries, leaders want to "look like good good leaders", because they need to get elected. In dictatorships the dictator doesn't need the people to think he is a good leader.  Democratic leaders don't want to "look bad", because then they don't win elections.

Comment: Hi James K, I am a person coming from an autocratic country ....

Comment: a very comprehensive explanation, thanks James K